# Integrating Leaderboarad Heyzap with sample app

Tags: android, leaderboard

Hi I am integrating Heyzap Leaderboard with my app for the first time. I have gone through [this](http://developers.heyzap.com/mobile/docs/android_sdk) document on the official website of Heyzap. But I feel they have guided only on the check-in Heyzap.

I downloaded sdk for leaderboard Heyzap and made that a library project in my project. But I'm getting errors in the below mentioned three java files inside that sdk.

1) **HeyzapLib.java**:

Errors-

- errror1

> i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
>
> The error says "FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES cannot be resolved or is not a field";

- error2

> new LeaderboardDialog(context, context.getPackageName(), levelId).show();
>
> The error says "The constructor LeaderboardDialog(Context, String, String) is undefined"

- error3

> LeaderboardScoreLauncher.launchScoreDialog(context, score, displayScore, levelId, gameIcon, context.getPackageName(), true, showScoreDialog);
>
> The error says "The method launchScoreDialog(Context, String, String, String, Drawable, String, boolean) in the type LeaderboardScoreLauncher is not applicable for the arguments (Context, String, String, String, Drawable, String, boolean, boolean)"

2) **HeyzapMarmalade.java**:

error:

> The import com.ideaworks3d cannot be resolved

3) **UnityHelper.java**:

error:

> The import com.unity3d cannot be resolved

Also, in the document that came along with the SDK, they have guided to make Leaderboards on their dashboard by finding the game by the package name and then adding the leaderboards. I have done as directed but then how to link that with my code?

Can anyone suggest anything or advise on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

I work on the Heyzap SDK, and might be able to help you out a little.

First, grab the latest copy of they Heyzap Leaderboard SDK (unless you're already using 3.3.7), and do a project->clean.

To fix the `Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES` bug, set the android version on the Heyzap SDK android project to android version 4.0+. That flag didn't exist before then.

For the Marmalade and Unity errors, there are jar files in the Heyzap SDK's `libs` folder that you'll need to add to the Java build path (select all the files, right click, navigate to Build Path -> Add To Build Path). Alternately, I'm pretty sure you can just delete those files if you're not using Marmalade or Unity.

The constructor errors have me stumped. I'm hoping you've grabbed a broken transient copy of the SDK we've accidentally pushed. Make sure you're using 3.3.7 and see if the errors go away.

If you have any other trouble, feel free to contact me.